# sum() over(partition by) equivalent in R

Tags: r

Here is my data:

```
    df <- data.frame(
  id=c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "4"),
  tube_placement=c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-15", "2020-01-01", "" ),
  tube_removal = c("2020-01-02", "2020-01-12", "2020-01-02", "", "2020-01-02", ""),
  attempts = c(1, 2, 1, "", 1, "")
)
df[df==""] <- NA

df$attempts <- as.numeric(df$attempts)
```

I would like to calculate a new column 'total_attempts' as:

```
id  tube_placement  tube_removal    attempts    total_attempts
1   2020-01-01      2020-01-02      1           3
1   2020-01-10      2020-01-12      2           3
2   2020-01-01      2020-01-02      1           1
2   2020-01-15      NA              NA          1
3   2020-01-01      2020-01-02      1           1
4   NA              NA              NA          NA
```

I have tried following:

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(total_attempts = sum(attempts))
```

The issue is that it fails to sum the ids that have NAs in them. Any advice or suggestion to improve my code?

Comment: Just add `na.rm = TRUE` as argument to `sum()` like `total_attempts = sum(attempts, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you! If you could post this as an answer. I will accept it as an answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use na.rm = TRUE to remove missing data from calculation, as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
id=c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "4"),
  tube_placement=c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-15", "2020-01-01", "" ),
  tube_removal = c("2020-01-02", "2020-01-12", "2020-01-02", "", "2020-01-02", ""),
  attempts = c(1, 2, 1, "", 1, "")
)

df[df==""] <- NA

df$attempts <- as.numeric(df$attempts)

df1 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(total_attempts = sum(attempts, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: @epenteado welcome to SO. It is good style to write `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of `T` and `F`, since `T` and `F` can be overwritten `T <- FALSE` unlike `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: Many thanks, Tim! I’ve always wondered why R writes True as TRUE and False as FALSE. In many other languages such as Python, F# True and False are the correct boolean, that’s why i prefer to write T and F in R. But i did edit already to fit our comment!